# Classical Impossible Constructions of Geometry proofs with Abstract Algebra.

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry

- Trisecting an angle (dividing a given angle into three equal angles),
- Squaring a circle (constructing a square with the same area as a given circle), and
- Doubling a cube (constructing a cube with twice the volume of a given cube).

Told that these problems could only be proved with abstract algebra.  I have no idea how to start.  I have found [this](http://www.math.toronto.edu/mathnet/questionCorner/impossconstruct.html) page.

I have an idea of what is being said, but no idea about how to exactly prove this.  Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: Did you read [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compass_and_straightedge#Impossible_constructions)?

Comment: @lhf yes, but I have, but I have having trouble how to "say it" with abstract algebra.

Comment: @MaoYiyi: Do you know any Galois theory? If not, that's where to start.

Comment: @ZhenLin, no need for Galois theory, just field theory. Except perhaps for proving that you cannot square the circle, i.e., that $\pi$ is transcendental. Hadlock solves the other two problems right at the start of the book.

Comment: @ZhenLin no idea about that, just started learning abstract algebra.

Comment: @lhf just started learning abstract algebra.  Which book are you talking about?

Comment: @MaoYiyi, see my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Field theory and its classical problems](http://maa-store.hostedbywebstore.com/FIELD-THEORY-CLASSICAL-PROBLEMS-Charles/dp/088385032X) by  Hadlock is a wonderful book motivated by these problems.

See also [Geometry: Euclid and Beyond](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/geometry/book/978-0-387-98650-0) by Hartshorne.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for, something to help me learn how to "say it" with abstract algebra.

Comment: Possibly the most elementary book I know of for this (much more elementary than Hadlock's and Hartshorne's books) is Benjamin Bold, **Famous Problems of Geometry and How to Solve Them**, Dover Publications, 1982. See also the references at the end of http://pballew.net/Constructable_17gon.pdf Quite a few of these references are freely available on-line at the URL's provided.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro you rock! thanks for the link.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro, thanks for the reference to Bold's book. I didn't know that book.